# How to add extra date in contribution template? or best way to do it?

Tags: civicontribute, profile, custom-fields, best-practice

We have 10 Financial Types and different online contribution based on those. I need to add an extra date field in contribution such as "Date of sponsorship".

I have already created 10 different custom field for that, just because we need to identify that date for different financial types separately. Then to add them into the contribution pages I need to create 10 different profile as well!!

Is there a way to make "Date of sponsorship" field as a common field like contribution note? or Receive date or What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating 10 "duplicate" fields is often a sign that there is something sub-optimal on the data modelling. As you start to realise, having the "wrong" data model is creating tons of problems further down the line, it's often better to come back to the root problem and try to fix it directly

Could you clarify your need?

Comment: Thanks!! 
Ok, to begin with I need 10 Financial type for sure. It could be more in future. 
Then when a person gives a donation through contribution page, I would like to create a date field,  where people can select a future date for sponsoring that particular contribution.

Comment: what do you mean future date for sponsoring? is this a pledge or a contribution that will be paid later?

Comment: 'Sponsoring a particular contribution' is using these terms differently than we understand them in the CiviCRM community, so we're having trouble understanding you. A 'contribution' is something a contact makes to the organization using CiviCRM; at its simplest it is making a donation payment throuh an online payment processor like PayPal. 'Sponsoring' is usually understood to be an artangement where one pays to help out the organization in exchange for recognition, often in the form of a listing or ad, especially for an event.

Comment: If you create a custom field set for contributions, then create a custom field in it called 'Date of sponsorship', this field will be available to be filled in for every contribution, no matter what its financial type. You can put it into a profile, and this profile can be used on 10 different contribution pages set up for different financial types. You can also use a priceset to offer 10 lines on a contribution page, each one allowing people to indicate they wanted to put money toward a different financial type. Contibution pages using this priceset would allow users to donate to any number o

Comment: Also, Thank you for pointing me to right direction. I will go this way. But i need one suggestion, I have already created 10 different custom sets with custom data in it. what is the best practice to keep the database efficient, do I keep them or delete them?

Comment: Also, there is a field available called "contribution Note" when creating a profile. But for the backend that field is nowhere to be seen, except for when i view the contribution. Is there away to make it visible for backend when entering a contribution?

Answer (score 2):

When defining the custom fieldset, you aren't restricted to 1 or All for the financial type. If you Ctrl+click, you can select all 10 of your financial types where the field should be available. Now you can create the custom field once, and it will be available for all 10 of those financial types. If more financial types are added that require the field, you can update the settings on the fieldset to include them; you aren't locked into the initial ones that you choose.

When you say that you need to "identify it separately", that sounds like something to be solved on the reporting side, not the data capture side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its best to delete all field and just have only one custom field which is linked with all financial type

also regarding "contribution Note" if this is a custom field and if it is visible only in view contribution - just edit the custom field (setting) and you can find a flag called "View Only?" undo the selection - then it will be available for Edit too

Comment: Thanks Ramesh! Please check my updated post above with screenshot...

Comment: hi Tapash, you didn't update the initial question, you created a new "answer". It's easier for everyone to follow the discussions if you create a new question instead of bundling two separate issues (the merging is a separate issue) could you create a new question?